# Struts form not displaying correctly

Tags: jsp, struts2

When I display and use the theme css_xhtml my textfield appears incorrectly. The textfield label is displayed on top of the textfield itself. I'm using the css_xhtml so that I can use my style "mediumfont". Do I need to extend the css_html theme ? Reading the docs about this theme it says - "Standard two-column CSS-based layout", is this causing my problem.

Here is my form -

```
<s:form action="add" theme="css_html">
    <s:textfield cssStyle="mediumfont" name="Bean.Name" label="Name" />
    <sj:submit targets="update" value="Add" />
</s:form>
```

Appologies if I shouldnt have added this to the jsp forums.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to find answers to tag questions is to look at http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/tag-reference.html

That is the definitive reference.

If you click on the link for textfield and then look for the attribute named labelposition you'll find your answer.

Comment: ok thanks, im using labelposition="left" for multiple textfields but they are not aligning correctly. Maybe I need to wrap the textfields in a <td> cell within a table? I'm not sure this is the correct way to fix this..

Comment: Sorry I have not used any theme outside to simple for a while, set the theme back to xhtml for that element.  I find themes to be picky, if you can do it in html and css go for it and set the theme to simple. Also if you get into ajax I find it far clearer to use something like jQuery and write all my own tags because then I don't need to think how struts will decide to name the id's.